# #links not sliding on Wordpress Landing page anymore (after installed https)

Tags: html, wordpress, https

I have a website www.kasnupaisezvaigzdes.lt. I made it on WordPress landing page. Everything was good, but i decided to move that page to Https:// protocol (SSL).

Installed WordPress https SSl plugin to make sure that wp content would be 100 % https, not mixed with https and http, green lock appeared as well.

But landing page links #link, #link2 etc. are not sliding anymore. Instead page is refreshing on particular spot. How to make again pages land on https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your database. make a copy for safe side as backup. Now replace all the urls in the sql file to https:// instead of http://

This will solve the issue

Comment: just export my database, open with editor and find all http:// and replace with https:// and reupload moded db?

Comment: Only changed my links to https:// instead of http:// Now it is working!

Comment: Export the database and open the file in any editor (notepad++). 
Find and replace all  http://www.kasnupaisezvaigzdes.lt with https://www.kasnupaisezvaigzdes.lt. Drop the database tables(i prefer create a new database) and import updated SQL file.